# Flashing N9005 (N9005XXUBMI5)

Tags: updates, root-access, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-3, odin

Firstly the reason why I've opened this thread is because previously over a year ago I wrongly flashed a s2 and I became a little scared of flashing phones. I got a samsung note 3 whose current os is Android 4.3 and since it was already rooted when I bought it (Unlocked French Phone) I can't get OTA updates. so I wanna flash it so that I can get OTA updates.

the existing baseband version is: N9005XXUBMI5
What I have downloaded is N9005ZHUENJ1 to upgrade from older version
I'm scared, would this work if I use this N9005ZHUENJ1 to update it over odin? 
do I have to repartition? 
and finally how do I have to do it for double checking

Answer (score 0):

No problem to use odin and flash stock firmware, newest you can vind on www.sammobile.com

On XDA I found you a thread to make sure you can succesfully use odin.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2704363

Hope this helps,

Regards,

Axel